# Screen flickers as Ubuntu boots up

Tags: boot, 16.04

Please have a look at [this YouTube video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=XF_brXu2Lp4).

The screen keeps flickering and I can't log in.

I've already installed nvidia driver and the system has been working fine for months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem a few days ago. The reason it is happening is because a program called X Windows (that is responsible drawing windows) is failing to start. Because X doesn't start, the session manager, (typically, lightdm or gdm) keeps trying to restart X. This is why your screen is flickering. each time X tries to start up, it takes control of your Gfx card, but... something along the way goes boom.

Anyways, the good news is that everything is probably ok, and a little work will get it fixed up.

As a first debugging step, even thought it seems paradoxical, could you try uninstalling the nvidia drivers with something like

```
$ sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*
```

and reboot your computer.

Comment: Incredible that this actually enabled the system to boot up into the gui! How does that work? Can I reinstall the nvidia packages now? Thanks!

Comment: So, you are now using the open source (actually contained in the linux kernel source code!) drivers for your video card.  If you want, you can try installing the non-free nvidia drivers. They do have some pretty ingenious performance tweaks.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same. Not sure if it is a stupid question but how do I run any command if I cannot log in?

Comment: Ok - I can answer myself - use recovery mode